# search the beginning of the key names and rename

Tags: javascript, regex, object, replace

I'd like to rename all keys "id a1", "id a2", "id b3", etc to just the name "id"
I'm looking for the regular expression to search all the current "id" key names.
And my function must work in IE : solution with arrow synthax is not working.

```js
var array1 = [{
  "id a1": 1, 
  "id a2": 2,
  name: 'ann',
  age: 24
}, {
  "id a1": 2,
  "id a2": 1,
  name: 'mark',
  age: 25
}, {
  "id b3": 3,
  "id b2": 1,
  name: 'henry',
  age: 24
}];

for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
  var tableHeaders = Object.keys(array1[i]);

  var newObject = {};

  for (var j = 0; j < tableHeaders.length; j++) {
    var oldKey = tableHeaders[j];
    var newKey = oldKey.replace(/id/g, 'id');
    newObject[newKey] = array1[i][oldKey];
  }

  array1[i] = newObject;
}

console.log(array1);
```

My expected output is like this:

```
var array1 = [{"id": 1,"id": 2,name: 'ann',age: 24}, { "id": 2, "id": 1, name: 'mark',age: 25}, {"id": 3,"id": 1, name: 'henry', age: 24}];
```

Comment: *to a unique name "id"* the same name is not unique.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @NinaScholz - Probably an English-as-a-second-language error, I'm guessing the OP meant "single" rather than "unique".

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I thought the OP confused it with the word “unified”.

Comment: sorry I have changed my question and array

Comment: you can not have two keys with the same value. the last one overwrites the earlier ones. with strict mode, object literals are not possible to have more than one same key.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/array/foreach)

```js
var array1 = [{ "id 1": 1, name: 'ann', age: 24 }, { "id 2": 2, name: 'mark', age: 25 }, { "id 3": 3, name: 'henry', age: 24 } ];

array1.forEach(o => {
  let k = Object.keys(o).find(k => k.indexOf("id") === 0);
  o.id = o[k];
  delete o[k];
});
console.log(array1);
```

Comment: you could use `includes` rather than `indexOf` if you wanted to save a couple of bytes 

Comment: @AndrewBone - That will be a problem if some other key has id in it like `state-id`, etc

Comment: sorry I have changed my question and array

Comment: @hetennunawi - Now your requirement is not valid as you expect duplicate keys in one object, whereas keys are unique in an object. That is against the DS

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to rename them all to `id` (a *single* name, not a *unique* name), then your regular expression is just a bit off. You want something along the lines of `/^id \d+$/g`:

- `^` to match start of input
- `id` to match `id` followed by a space
- `\d+` to match one or more digits
- `$` to match end of input.

Example:

```js
var array1 = [{ "id 1": 1, name: 'ann', age: 24 }, { "id 2": 2, name: 'mark', age: 25 }, { "id 3": 3, name: 'henry', age: 24 }, ];

for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
  var tableHeaders = Object.keys(array1[i]);

  var newObject = {}; 

  for (var j = 0; j < tableHeaders.length; j++) {
  var oldKey = tableHeaders[j];
  var newKey = oldKey.replace(/^id \d+$/g, 'id');
  newObject[newKey] = array1[i][oldKey];
  }

  array1[i] = newObject; 
}
console.log(array1);
```

Comment: This is good for visual learners like myself https://regexper.com/#%2F%5Eid%20%5Cd%2B%24%2F

Comment: @AndrewBone - Yeah. [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Bee7oj/1) is pretty good too.

Answer (score 0):

You could map the array and build a new object by iterationg all key value pairs and replace the key with starting `'id'` to `'id'`.

```js
var array = [{ "id 1": 1, name: 'ann', age: 24 }, { "id 2": 2, name: 'mark', age: 25 }, { "id 3": 3, name: 'henry', age: 24 } ],
    result = array.map(o =>
        Object.assign(
            ...Object.entries(o).map(([k, v]) => ({ [k.replace(/^id.+/, 'id')]: v }))
    ));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: sorry I have changed my question and array